# Can't post to symfony2

Tags: symfony, post

I'm using Symfony2 and i'm trying to POST a form to my controller, but my controller take it as a GET request everytime... Even when i'm using restclient, i put POST for the request but when i use $request->getMethod(), the answer is always GET :/

The source code is really simple :

```
<?php

namespace TC\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * @Route("/user/register")
    * @Method({"POST"})
    */
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        echo $request->getMethod();
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

And when i add the requirements _method: POST like this :

```
tc_user_register:
    path:     /user/register/
    defaults: { _controller: TCUserBundle:User:register }
    requirements:
      _method:  POST
```

I got this :
No route found for "POST /user/register"
Whatever i do, Symfony2 take it as a GET request, any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things @Xtroyer:

<kbd>1</kbd> If you use routing.yml file, `requirements: _method` is not recognised since Symfony 2.2, it is now:

```
tc_user_register:
    path:     /user/register/
    defaults: { _controller: TCUserBundle:User:register }
    methods:  [POST]
```

<kbd>2</kbd> If you use Annotations. @Method is not recognised if you don't mention the following use statement in your controller:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
```

<kbd>3</kbd> You can check what route is exactly registered with the following command?

```
php app/console router:debug | grep tc_user_register
```

*You should have:*

```
Name                       Method       Scheme      Host          Path
tc_user_register            POST         ANY        ANY       /user/register/
```

Comment: Thank you, when i use the command line and saw than everything was good, i just saw that i sent my request to /user/register and than my route is /user/register/ --' Now it's working :D